# I blocked all facebook's domain, intrusive iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

for various reasons I don't want to be tracked by facebook's iframes so I edited my hosts file, now whenever I run into a site that's embedding facebook's iframes I get this nasty and intruding layer.

I'm on Chrome is there a way to run a custom JS on each page load or some other mean to fix this annoyance?

[image: iframe who's being a pain]

Comment: Probably. But we'd need some information about the frames, and whether they all share a common targetable attribute.

Why not just add the domain to adblock?

Comment: well, usually the src attribute matches *facebook*

Comment: I suggest you use a plugin like [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com) (which can work along side adblock) instead of manually editing your hosts file.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't see the benefits this plugin would add, I really want to block certain sites at a networking level :) also, I suspect that this would not help with the iframe annoyance

Comment: @sathia: I use that plugin, and flightradar24.com works just fine in Chrome, there's no weird grey box :-)  Maybe you can use it along with your hosts file :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Does it block outbound requests, or does it just hide elements in the DOM?

Comment: @JoeCullinan: Pretty sure it just simply blocks the script file(s) from loading in the browser, so that the code never runs.  I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a decent way to deal with this, instead of pointing to 0.0.0.0 I'm overriding to an internal IP where a web-server is running, instead of a connection error I receive a 404[image: worksforme]

which is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at grease monkey:
It has limited support for chrome, but it might be enough for what you want

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: I've see this extension, but I'd rather not allow an app to have access to all my browsing data, isn't there a way to inject a simple js file?